# Spinning cursor at command line while trying to npm install bower

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

After typing the command `sudo npm install -g bower` the terminal moves to the next line and displays a rotating backslash  character inside of a cursor. It never progresses from that point on. Any ideas as to what I can do? This is running in Crouton on a Chromebook, but I don't think that is an issue as I've installed other components using npm in the past.

[image]

Comment: Is there any output in the `npm-debug.log`? Are you on a *particularly* slow / disfunctional connection?

Answer (score 5):

If this happens with all packages, it's likely an issue with HTTPS.  Try setting node to use HTTP:

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

and then attempt install again.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar issue and setting

```
npm config set spin=false
```

resolved the issue

found suggested solution here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5340

Comment: How is this a solution?  All it does is stop the spinning.  Still doesn't do anything.

Comment: This isn't a proper answer, but may actually improve performance according to this [hacker news post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10974929)

Answer (score 0):

Could be a firewall issue if you normally use a proxy to connect to the internet. Try this first and make sure you use your actual host and port.

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Resource is here